# How to get a Sales order number against a purchase order

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2009

I have created a Purchase `order(Ex: PO_001)` while creating a sales `order(Ex: SO_001)` by using menu item button "**Purchase Order**" in the Sales order form. Now I want to update some fields in `SO_001` when a field update in `PO_001` from purchase order form. For this I need to select `SO_001` from `PO_001` first.

How can I do that?

Comment: you can start with sharing your code and then specifically asking what is wrong or how to improve.

Comment: Hi Shivam,Thanks for quick reply. I haven't write any code yet. All I need to know that, what is the relation between PO which is created against a sales order.And how can I know the SO no. which is related to that PO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AX2009 table method PurchTable.checkUpdate:

> salesTable = SalesTable::find(this.InterCompanyOriginalSalesId);

Answer (score 1):

For AX 2012, query table `InterCompanyPurchSalesReference` like for example:

```
InterCompanyPurchSalesReference reference;

while select reference where reference.PurchId == 'PO_001'
{
    info(reference.SalesId);
}
```